# Experiments in vitro vs those with dead organisms and fixated tissue

Tags: cell-biology

Does the term *in vitro* necessarily imply that the organism/organs/cells of study are  *dead*?

If not, is there an alternative latin term to refer to studies of *dead* biological matter ? (e.g. in Connectomics where the tissue is biologically dead, and has been fixated and sectioned with a microtome)

Comment: _Ex vivo_ perhaps? _In mortum_? :)

Answer (score 3):

**Does the term *in vitro* necessarily imply that the organism/organs/cells of study are dead?**

No, *in vitro* studies are often carried out with living cells - just think of *in vitro* fertilisation. The nearest I can come up with for what you want is **histology**, but I think even this encompasses studies of living cells and tissues.